# Как сделать drupal 7 адаптивным?

Tags: drupal, jquery

Как сделать drupal 7 адаптивным?

Может есть:

1. видеоуроки;
2. готовые адаптивные голые движки;
3. какие модули для этого используются.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я так понимаю речь идет об Адаптивной верстке?
Если да - то тут работа чисто с шаблонами, CSS

Answer (score 0):

Возмите за основу данную тему: [AdaptiveTheme](https://drupal.org/project/adaptivetheme). Вот [урок](http://la.by/blog/sozdanie-sobstvennoy-temy-s-ispolzovaniem-adaptivetheme)